# access tablix1 value in tablix2 using SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Hi is there any way to access tablix1 values in tablix2?

i've a textbox1 in tablix1 and i want to assign this textbox1 value in tablix2 textbox.

Is it possible in SSRS 2008?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access any report item from anywhere without indicating its tablix name by expression
[ReportItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934329.aspx).